# How to cache a page via a Chrome Extension service worker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to cache the contents of a website I visit using a Chrome extension, but I am unable to figure out how to save the response of the page into chrome.storage. I would then like get the cache to load the cached page at a different date. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[MyCache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mycache/cfgbkangadnolaljljeofhegbkjedpmf) automatically stores saved copies of the pages you visit.